# Process.MainWindowTitle returns empty string in C#

Tags: c#

I have windows 11 . I have a console application in VS2019(C#).
I am trying to launch calculator exe thru system.Diagnostics.Process.

code snippet:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe");

//startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

var myProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);

myProcess.WaitForInputIdle();

Console.Write("Main window Title : " + myProcess.MainWindowTitle.ToString());
```

After running above code, calculator exe is getting launched but myProcess.MainWindowTitle returns a empty string. I am not able to understand this fact. Please help.

Tried:

I have tried running above code in order to fetch the the value of MainWidowsTitle. But even though the calculator is getting launched, the value of 'MainWindowTitle' is empty string.

Expected value : MainWindowTitle should return a value as 'Calculator' as the window name for calc.exe is that.

Comment: The issue you’re experiencing is probably due to the fact that the MainWindowTitle property does not immediately get populated after a process starts. It takes some time for the system to start the process and for the process to create its main window. You could try and introduce a short delay with `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` and test if this is indeed the problem.

Comment: @MySpaceDotNet The delay is not needed, `WaitForInputIdle()` already does that

Comment: Isn't `WaitForInputIdle()` manly used to determine when the process has finished its setup? Does it guarantee that the window had enough time to set the title? Maybe I am completely wrong.

Comment: @MySpaceDotNet a process enters an idle state when the CPU has completed all tasks (which i assume would include everything in setup as well)

Comment: @TP95 No necessarily.  If the startup process involves performing some non-UI work the message loop could easily be idle for an extended period of time before the "proper" window is set up and has whatever title the OP is looking for.  It might have a splash screen or some other placeholder while the startup background tasks are being performed.  It need not even be something on the order of seconds; it could be just a few frames while it's loading something off of disk that doesn't need the UI thread.

Comment: The Process that starts the executable is not the same as the Process to which the UI interface belongs to. Compare, in Task Manager, your Process ID (`myProcess.Id`) with the one of the application you just run

Comment: On my system, `calc.exe` actually launches `calculatorapp.exe`. The secondary app also reports back an empty `MainWindowTitle`, though.

Comment: MainWindowTitle returns an empty string when the process has terminated or doesn't have a main window.  The first condition is the issue here, on Win10 and up, calc.exe merely starts the appx flavor and terminates.  Same thing happens for notepad.exe on Win11.